# Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in}}{n [\ln (n)]^{\alpha}}$ absolutely convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

For which values of $\alpha$ the serie $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in}}{n [\ln (n)]^{\alpha}}$$ converges absolutely? and for which values is conditional convergent?

I know that $\sum e^{in}$ diverges (I proved it before), and now I think I need to consider cases for $\alpha$: if $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha\neq0$.

If $\alpha=0$, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{in}}{n [\ln (n)]^{\alpha}}$ converges by Dirichlet test.

Now I just need to analyze the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}|\frac{e^{in}}{n [\ln (n)]^{\alpha}}|$, but I think it would be the same result because all the terms involved in the series would be positive, in conclusion the whole serie is Absolutely convergent.

But if $\alpha\neq0$, should I consider the cases where $\alpha<0$ and $\alpha>0$ or would be more simple considering the general case?

Also can someone give a hint/help to proof the rest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is conditionally convergent (by the Dirichlet test) for any $\alpha$ since $\frac{1}{n \ln(n)^\alpha}$ decreases to zero as $n \to \infty$ for any $\alpha$ (I'm cheating a bit here because $\frac{1}{n\ln(n)^\alpha}$ is not a monotone decreasing sequence; however, it is decreasing for large enough $n$ and the limit is zero which is sufficient). To test absolute convergence, you need $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)^\alpha}$$ to converge (since $\lvert e^{in} \rvert = 1$ for all $n$). For this we use the integral test. Using $u = \ln (x)$, we see $$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x \ln(x)^\alpha} = \int^{\infty}_{\ln(2)} \frac{du}{u^\alpha}.$$ This converges iff $\alpha > 1$; thus the sum also converges absolutely for $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: why the last integral converges iff $\alpha>1?$

Comment: To sum up, the serie it's absolutely convergent if $\alpha>1$ and it's conditionally convergent if $\alpha\le 1$?

Comment: You can explicitly do the integral: $$\int^\infty_{\ln(2)} \frac{du}{u^\alpha} = \left.\frac{1}{(1-\alpha)u^{\alpha - 1}}\right|^{u \to \infty}_{u = \ln(2)}.$$ Now we need the power on the bottom to be positive in order for convergence as $u \to \infty$ so we need $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One could also equally well use the Cauchy condensation test instead of the integral test.

Comment: @User8128: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\beta \ln(n)^\alpha}$ is known as a *Bertrand's series* and should be known by everyone as convergent  iff 1) $\beta>1$ or 2) $\beta=1$  AND $\alpha>1$. The second case is of course proved as you did.

Comment: @Bernard good info! I hadn't heard the term 'Bertrand Series' before.

Comment: @LutzL Would be easier to use the Cauchy condensation test ? or it's the same to use one or the other

Comment: The CCT requires to test the convergence of $$\sum2^na_{2^n}=\sum\frac{2^n}{2^n\ln(2^n)^α}=\sum\frac1{(\ln2)^α\,n^α}$$ and now needs a second iteration of CCT or the knowledge of the general harmonic series. So not essentially easier, but does not require knowledge of integration.

Comment: @LutzL :) oh ok